# Positioning button at bottom of div with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a series of divs positioned side by side on my page. I've positioned them using flexbox. Inside each box I have a button, which I want placed at the bottom of the box. I've looked at other questions similar to mine, but none of those solutions have worked. I've tried adding

```
p {
  margin: 0
}

.movie_list_button {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

but this doesn't do anything. I've also tried `p { flex-grow: 1; }`, but that didn't work either. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div class="movie_group">
    <div class="movie_list">
        <ul>
        <li>
          <p><b>Box 1 text 1</b></p>
          <p>Box 1 text 2. No matter how large this text is, I want the button to stick to the bottom of the box</p>
          <div class="movie_list_button">
            <button>Button</button>
          </div>
          </li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="movie_list">
        <ul>
        <li>
          <p><b>Box 2 text 1</b></p>
          <p>Box 2 text 2. No matter how large this text is, I want the button to stick to the bottom of the box</p>
          <div class="movie_list_button">
            <button>Button</button>
          </div>
         </li> 
        </ul> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.movie_group {
    margin-top: 120px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.movie_list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-basis: 30%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 300px;
   /*  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; */
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
}

.movie_list_button {
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4pbzfct3/64/

Comment: To start with although probably not related but your HTML is invalid, `li` must be children of a `ul` not a `div`.

Comment: ah sorry, I just posted my code. @Paulie_D thanks for pointing that out, I just fixed that.

Comment: Also `ul` can only have `li` as children. You really need to get your HTML is order first.

Comment: You where on the right track, but your HTML structure was totally messed up : a bit of cleaning and tada : https://jsfiddle.net/h6vmLc01/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus oh thank you! It's been a while since I've done anything with HTML, so could you explain why I couldn't have my button inside the list element?

Comment: It  was not a flex child, so margin-top:auto had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can take your button out of the "flow" of your flexbox by giving it's parent div "position: relative" and the div around the button "position: absolute". From there, you can use top, right, left, and bottom to move your button around, relative to its parent element. What I will post below places the button in the bottom left, but you can move it wherever you like. You can also use negative values to move it outside of it's parent if you like.

```
.movie_group {
  margin-top: 120px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.movie_list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  **position: relative;**
  /*  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; */
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
}

.movie_list_button {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: auto;
  **position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;**
}
```

If you don't like the idea of using position absolute and relative to move the button, you could also make a flexbox within a flexbox to position your button. This would require you to change your HTML. Ultimately, this will be better in the long run because it is already psuedo responsive.

You would move the button div outside of your ul, and then would another div around the ul. So you would have two "flex-items" in your new movie_list flexbox. You would then add "flex-direction: column" back onto your .movie_list class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="movie_group">
      <div class="movie_list">
        <div class="inner-flex">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p><b>Box 1 text 1</b></p>
              <p>
                Box 1 text 2. No matter how large this text is, I want the
                button to stick to the bottom of the box
              </p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="movie_list_button">
          <button>Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="movie_list">
        <div class="inner-flex">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p><b>Box 2 text 1</b></p>
              <p>
                Box 2 text 2. No matter how large this text is, I want the
                button to stick to the bottom of the box
              </p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="movie_list_button">
          <button>Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
.movie_group {
  margin-top: 120px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.movie_list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
}

.inner-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.movie_list_button {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```